# How to run-length encode 'EEDDDNE' to '2E3DNE'?

Tags: c#, loops, replace

Explanation: The task itself is that we have 13 strings (stored in the sor[] array) like the one in the title or **'EEENKDDDDKKKNNKDK'**
and we have to shorten it in a way that if there's two or more of the same letter next to eachother then we have to write it in the form of 'NumberoflettersLetter'

So by this rule, **'EEENKDDDDKKKNNKDK'** would become **'3ENK4D3K2NKDK'**

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] sor = new string[] { "EEENKDDDDKKKNNKDK", "'EEDDDNE'" };

        char holder;
        int counter = 0;
        string temporary;
        int indexholder;
        for (int i = 0; i < sor.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int q = 0; q < sor[i].Length; q++)
            {
                holder = sor[i][q];
                indexholder = q;
                counter = 0;
                while (sor[i][q] == holder)
                {
                    q++;
                    counter++;
                }
                if (counter > 1)
                {
                    temporary = Convert.ToString(counter) + holder;
                    sor[i].Replace(sor[i].Substring(indexholder, q), temporary); // EX here
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Sorry I didn't make the error clear, it says that :

> `"The value of index and length has to represent a place inside the string (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException) - name of parameter: length"`

...but I have no clue what's wrong with it, maybe it's a tiny little mistake, maybe the whole thing is messed up, so this is why I'd like someone to help me with this D:
(Ps 'indexholder' is there because i need it for another exercise)

**EDIT:**

'sor' is the string array that holds these strings (there are 13 of them) like the one mentioned in the title or in the example

Comment: `"The error says the issue is with the Replace part"` -- Ok, so what is the error?

Comment: definition of `sor` please

Comment: In any case Replace doesn't work directly on the source string but it returns a new string with the chars replaces

Comment: I guess one issue is that when you replace parts of your string you shorten it (of Course, because that's the purpose of the encoding), but your index stays at the old position. This will lead to skipping the parts inbetween.

Comment: Wait, so you are telling me that the error you receive is a compiler error that says, verbatim, `"[the issue is with the Replace part]"`?

Comment: I think you should read what is a [mcve] because as is your code cannot be used to check against your question

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex for this:

```
Regex.Replace("EEENKDDDDKKKNNKDK", @"(.)\1+", m => $"{m.Length}{m.Groups[1].Value}")
```

Explanation:

- `(.)` matches any character and puts it in group #1
- `\1+` matches group #1 as many times can it can

Comment: Though reasonable, the aim is to discover and explain the problem with the OP's code, not replace it entirely

Answer (score 2):

Shortening the same string inplace is more difficult then construction a new one while iterating the old one char by char. If you plan to iteratively add to a string it is better to use the [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) - class instead of adding directly to a string (performance reasons).

You can streamline your approach by using  [IEnumerable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) function wich does the iteration on one string for you automatically:

```
using System; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{ 
    public static string RunLengthEncode(string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) // avoid null ref ex and do simple case
            return "";

        // we need a "state" between the differenc chars of s that we store here:
        char curr_c = s[0];  // our current char, we start with the 1st one
        int count = 0;       // our char counter, we start with 0 as it will be 
                             // incremented as soon as it is processed by Aggregate 
                             // ( and then incremented to 1)

        var agg = s.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (acc, c) =>   // StringBuilder
            // performs better for multiple string-"additions" then string itself 
        {
            if (c == curr_c)
                count++;  // same char, increment
            else
            {
                // other char
                if (count > 1) // store count if  > 1
                    acc.AppendFormat("{0}", count);
                acc.Append(curr_c); // store char

                curr_c = c; // set current char to new one
                count = 1; // startcount now is 1
            }
            return acc;
        });
        // add last things
        if (count > 1) // store count if  > 1
            agg.AppendFormat("{0}", count);
        agg.Append(curr_c); // store char

        return agg.ToString(); // return the "simple" string
    }
```

Test with

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(RunLengthEncode("'EEENKDDDDKKKNNKDK' ")); 

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output for `"'EEENKDDDDKKKNNKDK' "`:

```
'3ENK4D3K2NKDK'
```

---

Your approach **without** using the same string is more like this:

```
var data = "'EEENKDDDDKKKNNKDK' ";
char curr_c = '\x0';           // avoid unasssinged warning 
int count = 0;                 // counter for the curr_c occurences in row
string result = string.Empty;  // resulting string

foreach (var c in data)        // process every character of data in order     
{
    if (c != curr_c)           // new character found
    {
        if (count > 1)         // more then 1, add count as string and the char
            result += Convert.ToString(count) + curr_c;
        else if (count > 0)    // avoid initial `\x0` being put into string
             result += curr_c;

        curr_c = c;            // remember new character
        count = 1;             // so far we found this one 
    }
    else
        count++;               // not new, increment counter
}

// add the last counted char as well
if (count > 1)
    result += Convert.ToString(count) + curr_c;
else
    result += curr_c;

// output
Console.WriteLine(data + " ==> " + result);
```

Output:

```
'EEENKDDDDKKKNNKDK'  ==>  '3ENK4D3K2NKDK'
```

Instead of using the indexing operator `[]` on your string and have to struggle with indexes all over I use `foreach c in "sometext" ...` which will proceed char-wise through the string - much less hassle.

If you need to run-length encode an array/list (your `sor`) of strings, simply apply the code to each one (preferably by using `foreach s in yourStringList ...`.

Comment: No worries.   Nicely written otherwise

Comment: @MickyD and now its commented througout code as well ;)